# Dashes vs underscores in URLs for SEO

Tags: url, seo

What do search engines presently prefer us to use as word separators in URLs: dashes or underscores? Should I use http://example.com/dash-underscore
or http://example.com/dash_underscore?

Comment: Also see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119312/dash-vs-underscore

Answer (score 2):

Search engines tend to treat them differently. Google likes to treat two words joined by an underscore as a single word, but dashes are considered to be seperating puntuation. Try it out yourself!

I tried search for search_engine and search-engine. The first gave me pages and urls with that exact phrase, the second was a more general search, treating the dash `-` like a space.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the blog sites nowadays build URL slugs using dashes as opposed to underscores as it is a lot easier to read so I wouldn't be surprised if search engines score dashes higher on the results than underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Use hyphens.

I have asked several SEO consultants and they always say to use hyphens in URLs for separate words. That seems in line with practices on most commons sites I've looked at.