# Using dash in the URL query in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

Can we use dashes (-) in the `Route` template in ASP.NET Core?

```
// GET: api/customers/5/orders?active-orders=true
[Route("customers/{customer-id}/orders")]
public IActionResult GetCustomerOrders(int customerId, bool activeOrders)
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

*(The above code doesn't work)*

Comment: but why do you want to do that?

Comment: Yea, good question. Why would you want do that in the first place? the route parameters usually directly map to the variable name, so `Route("customers/{customerid}/orders")` should work since thats the name of your variable. However, you can try `public IActionResult GetCustomerOrders([FromRoute(Name = "customer-id")]int customerId, bool activeOrders)`

Comment: @Tseng - 1. "We recommend that you use hyphens (-) instead of underscores (_) in your URLs." https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=en
2. I tried your solution and it works. I also can have `..., [FromQuery(Name = "active-orders")] bool activeOrders)`. Super. Problem solved.
Could you please post these 2 comments as an answer for the sake of others?

Comment: @AmanB - It is recommended to use dashes instead of camelCase or hyphen in a URL. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2318376/538387

Comment: @AmanB as a designer I think it looks much better, and the url is something the customer sees

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The route parameters usually directly map to the action's **variable name**, so `[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]` should work since that's the name of your variable (`int customerId`).

You **don't need** dashes there, the part within the curly braces `{}` will never appear as a part of the generated url, it will always be replaced by the content you pass from browser or the variables you pass to the url generator.

`customers/{customerId}/orders` will always be `customers/1/orders` when `customerId` is set to 1, so there's no point trying to force it to `{customer-id}`.

However, you can try public

```
[Route("customers/{customer-id}/orders")]
IActionResult GetCustomerOrders([FromRoute(Name = "customer-id")]int customerId, bool activeOrders)
```

to bind the `customerId` from a unconventional route name, if you wish. But I'd strongly advise against it, as it just adds unnecessary code which has **absolutely zero-effect** on your generated urls.

The above generates (and parses) the **exactly same** url as

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
IActionResult GetCustomerOrders(int customerId, bool activeOrders)
```

and is much more readable code.

For the query part, as you figured it out in the comments, it makes sense to add the dashes via `[FromQuery(Name = "active-orders")] bool activeOrders`, since that really affects the generated url.

### New in ASP.NET Core 2.2

In ASP.NET Core 2.2 you'll get a new option to 'slugify' your routes (only supported when using the new Route Dispatcher instead of the default Mvc Router).

A route of `blog\{article:slugify}`  will (when used with `Url.Action(new { article = "MyTestArticle" })`) generate `blog\my-test-article` as url.

Can also be used in default routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home:slugify}/{action=Index:slugify}/{id?}");
```

For further details see the [ASP.NET Core 2.2-preview 3 annoucement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/10/17/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview3-now-available/).

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on **Tseng** answer to the question. for ASP NET CORE to use *"slugify"* transformer you need to register it first like so:

```
public class SlugifyParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
{
    public string TransformOutbound(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) { return null; }

        return Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), 
                             "([a-z])([A-Z])",
                             "$1-$2",
                             RegexOptions.CultureInvariant,
                             TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).ToLowerInvariant();
    }
}
```

and then in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddRouting(options =>
    {
        options.ConstraintMap["slugify"] = typeof(SlugifyParameterTransformer);
    });
}
```

[Code from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#parameter-transformer-reference)